# A service cannot spawn a new program unless it's running under Local System Account 

Tags: service, execute, localsystem

First of all, I'm not sure if this is generic to services in general, but the problem I'm having is pretty specific, it has got to do with the SageTV service component.

Since there isn't much help over at the SageTV forums regarding this specific subject, I thought maybe this was a generic issue with services and therefore worth asking here at Stackoverflow.

Here goes:

I'm running the SageTV windows service with a plugin activated which is supposed to execute external programs.  When running under the Local System Account (with the "Interact with the desktop option" enabled), this works fine.  For testing purposes I'm using notepad.exe as the program to execute.

Then I created a new user (let's call it mediabrowser) and changed the SageTV service so it would run as that user.  When I do that, the SageTV plugin no longer executes notepad.  It just does nothing, I don't get any errors or anything, it's just that nothing happens when notepad should be getting executed.

The mediabrowser user has administrative priviliges.  The option to interact with the desktop is only available for the Local System Account, and I believe that normal users are always allowed to interact with the desktop anyways.

Is this a general issue with services?  If so, what permissions might my mediabrowser user need in order for this to work?  I'm pretty sure this is because of permission differences between my mediabrowser user and the Local System Account.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh OK.  Now I feel like an idiot.  I just launched the tast manager on the machine and I can see that there are tons of notepad.exe processes under the mediabrowser user so I guess that notepad IS being executed correctly.  It's just not being shown on the desktop.

So I guess this just works :-)

Comment: Guess you've long since discovered the difference between session 0 and the user's sessions :-)